# Connecting to the docker MySql in Mac os x

Tags: docker

We have created the container in docker and pull the data into it. But it is erroring out as 'Error response from daemon: conflict, The "/mysql-cont" is already in use by container.' when executing the below command to connect the MySql

docker run --name mysql-cont -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD= -d tutum/mysql:5.6.

Please help me to resolve. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Update to the current version of Docker.

Comment: At present I am using Docker version 1.10.3